# Create a real InterestBearing Token

Tags: token-2022

From what I've understand of the Interest-Bearing extension from Token2022, it is actually a cosmetic feature, the balances seen on explorers, on wallets do not change. The amounts do not change, only the amount_UI.

I know real Interest Bearing protocols on Ethereum, like Titano for exemple (auto-rebase).
A use case would be for exemple Interest-Bearing stablecoin (based on bonds).

Is there any way to do that ? The balances of a held token would change (without having to actually "mint" the tokens with a transaction) over time ?